# Determinant from Paul Garrett's Definition of the Characteristic Polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, determinant, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id} \DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$
On pg. 390 of Paul Garrett's [notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/algebra/notes/Whole.pdf) on Algebra, a definition for the characteristic polynomial is given, which I discuss here.

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Consider the $F$-module $M=F[x]\otimes_F V$ and give it an $F[x]$-module structure by extending the scalars via the natural inclusion $F\to F[x]$. Thus $M$ is a free $F[x]$-module of rank $n$. Now we can think of $1\otimes T-x\otimes \id_V$ as a member of $\End_{F[x]}(M)$.

**Definition.** The ***characteristic polynomial*** of $T$ is then defined as the unique polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ such that the $n$-th exterior power map
$$\Lambda^n_{F[x]}(1\otimes T-x\otimes \id_V):\Lambda^n_{F[x]} M\to \Lambda^n_{F[x]}M$$
is same as multiplication by $p(x)$ with the identity map on $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}M$.

On the other hand, the following is well known:

**Definition.** Let $\lambda\in F$ is a scalar in $F$, we have a linear operator $T-\lambda I$ on $V$, whose determinant is defined as the unique scalar $\theta\in F$ such that the map
$$\Lambda^n_F (T-\lambda I):\Lambda^n_F V\to \Lambda^n_F V$$
is $\theta$ times the identity map on $V$.

> **Question.** How do we see that $\det(T-\lambda I)=p(\lambda)$ under the above definitions.

I have a feeling that this should be rather straightforward from the definitions but I can't see it. I am just beginning to learn exterior algebra over modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, notice that exterior powers commute with base change (Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra with a View..., Proposition A2.2, p. 576), hence

$$\Lambda^n_{F[x]} (F[x] \otimes_F V)=F[x] \otimes_F \Lambda^n_{F}V$$

You can easily check, that the following diagram (of $F$-modules) commutes ($m(\lambda)$ is the map $x \mapsto \lambda$ from the other answer):

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F[x] \otimes_F V @>{m(\lambda) \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}>> V\\
@V{1 \otimes T - x \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}VV @V{T-\lambda \operatorname{id}_V}VV \\
F[x] \otimes_F V @>{m(\lambda) \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}>> V
\end{CD}

Taking the exterior algebra is functorial, hence we get a commutative diagram (I will omit the exterior power symbols for the name of the maps, unless for the $\det$)

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F[x] \otimes_F \Lambda^n_{F}V @>{m(\lambda) \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}>> \Lambda^n_{F}V\\
@V{1 \otimes T - x \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}VV @V{\det(T-\lambda \operatorname{id}_V)}VV \\
F[x] \otimes_F \Lambda^n_{F}V @>{m(\lambda) \otimes \operatorname{id}_V}>> \Lambda^n_{F}V
\end{CD}

Using the identification $\Lambda^n_{F}V = F$ and the definition for $p(x)$ above (set $P(\lambda)=\det(T-\lambda \operatorname{id}_V)$), this is precisely the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F[x] @>{m(\lambda)}>> F\\
@V{\cdot p(x)}VV @V{\cdot P(\lambda)}VV \\
F[x] @>{m(\lambda)}>> F
\end{CD}

In particular, if we track the image of $1 \in F[x]$, we get the desired

$$p(\lambda) = P(\lambda).$$

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: On a more careful reading, I am having trouble understanding the step where the functoriality of exterior powers is used. The modules $F[x]\otimes_F V$ is thought of as an $F[x]$-module (by extending scalars). So to use functoriality, $V$ too should be thought of as an $F[x]$-module. The relevant $F[x]$-module structure on $V$ I can think of is given by $p(x)\cdot v=p(\lambda)v$. But $V$ is not a free $F[x]$-module and it is also not clear why $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}(T-\lambda I)$ is multiplication by determinant of $T$. Can you please answer this. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the use of the notation $m(\lambda)\otimes \id_V$ is not making sense to me. I don't see why "$\otimes$" is appearing here.We just want that $p(x)\otimes v$ is sent to $p(\lambda)v$ and it is easy to see that it is well defined.

Comment: During the whole proof, we consider the diagram as a diagram of $F$-modules. And we take the exterior power with respect to $F$, use functiorality and then use the base change theorem, I cited. Then in the last step, where we plugin the definiton of the char. polynomial, we consider it as a $F[x]$-module. How does this bother yoh?

Comment: The $\otimes$-notation from the map comes from $F \otimes_F V=V$, hence the right side of the first diagram is also a tensor product. Of course this is precisely the map, you defined by hand in your last comment.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of everything as an $F[x]$-module. Let me think through the proof again.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: I am still confused. To get the second commutative square, we have taken the exterior power with respect to $F$. So the left vertical map in the second diagram would be $\Lambda^n_F(1\otimes T-x\otimes\id_V):\Lambda^n_F(F[x]\otimes_F V)\to \Lambda^n_F(F[x]\otimes_F V)$. I do not see how do we use the theorem you cited here since we have $\Lambda^n_{F}(F[x]\otimes_F V)$ rather than $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}(F[x]\otimes_F V)$. Thank you.

Comment: To get from the first commutative square to the second, you are actually applying the functor $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}$ to everything.  Note that $V$ can be considered as a $F[x]$-module via $m(\lambda)$ (so that all the maps in the first square are $F[x]$-linear), and then $\Lambda^n_{F[x]} V$ can be naturally identified with $\Lambda^n_F V$ (the universal properties they have can be shown to be equivalent; more generally, if $M$ is an $R$-module and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ that annihilates $M$, then $\Lambda^n_RM\cong \Lambda^n_{R/I} M$; here $R=F[x]$ and $I=\ker(m(\lambda))$).

Comment: @EricWofsey This makes sense to me. Let me think about it thoroughly and then comment back. I will soon reply to your answer on my other question too.

Comment: @EricWofsey I understand it finally. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id} \DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$Fix a scalar $\lambda\in F$. There is an evaluation map $m_\lambda:F[x]\rightarrow F$ such that $x\mapsto \lambda$. It induces a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_{F[x]} M @>{\Lambda^n_{F[x]}(1\otimes T-x\otimes \id_V)}>> \Lambda^n_{F[x]} M\\
@V{m_\lambda}VV @V{m_\lambda}VV \\
\Lambda^n_F V @>{\Lambda^n_F (T-\lambda I)}>> \Lambda^n_F V
\end{CD}

In particular $m_\lambda(p(x))=p(\lambda)$, so $\theta=\operatorname{det}(T-\lambda I)=p(\lambda)$.

Comment: I guess this really isn't an answer, and just a restatement of the conclusion, but maybe it makes the issue clearer for you...

Comment: I do not see why the diagram commutes. In fact I am not clear as to how we get the vertical maps in the diagram. We have a map $m_\lambda :F[x]\to F$. How do we get the vertical maps $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}M\to \Lambda^n_F V$, also labelled by $m_\lambda$. Lastly, $\Lambda^n_{F[x]}M$ and $\Lambda^n_F V$ are modules over different rings, so this should be addressed somewhere.