# Universal Linearizer of Alternating Multi-$F[x]$-Linear Maps is Same as that of Multi-$F$-Linear Maps.

Tags: modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $M=F[x]\otimes_F V$. We can consider $M$ as an $F[x]$-module by extending scalars using the inclusion $F\to F[x]$.

**Fact 1.** There is an $F$-module $\Lambda^k_FM$ and a multi-$F$-linear map $\pi:M^k\to \Lambda^k_F M$ such that all alternating multi-$F$-linear maps defined on $M^k$ factor through $\pi$ to give a unique $F$-linear map from $\Lambda^k_F M$.

**Fact 2.** There is an $F[x]$-module $\Lambda^k_{F[x]}M$ and a multi-$F[x]$-linear map $\Pi:M^k\to \Lambda^k_{F[x]} M$ such that all alternating multi-$F[x]$-linear maps defined on $M^k$ factor through $\Pi$ to give a unique $F[x]$-linear map from $\Lambda^k_{F[x]}M$.

Note that we are treating $\Lambda^k_F M$ and $\Lambda^k_{F[x]} M$ merely as notations. They may have nothing to do with each other.

> **Question.** Is it true that the gadget $\Pi:M^k\to \Lambda^k_{F[x]}M$ fills the bill for the gadget $\pi:M^k\to \Lambda^k_F M$?

In other words, if suppose we have a multi-$F$-linear map $f:M^k\to N$, then does there exists a unique $F$-linear map $\tilde f:\Lambda^k_{F[x]} M\to N$ whose composition with $\Pi$ is same as $f$?

The motivation for this question is from my discussion with @MooS in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630222/determinant-from-paul-garrets-definition-of-the-characteristic-polynomial) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  For instance, take $n=k=2$, so $M=F[x]^2$, $\Lambda^k_{F[x]}M=F[x]$, and $\Pi:M^2\to F[x]$ is the map that sends $((a,b),(c,d))$ to $ad-bc$ (for $a,b,c,d\in F[x]$).  Write $a_n$ for the degree $n$ coefficient of a polynomial $a\in F[x]$.  Let $N=F$ and define $f:M^2\to N$ by $f((a,b),(c,d))=a_0d_1-b_1c_0$.  Then $f$ is $F$-bilinear and alternating.  However, $f$ cannot factor though $\Pi$: for instance, $\Pi((1,1),(x,x))=0$ but $f((1,1),(x,x))=1$.